# MySQL - Access Partitions Through Views

Tags: mysql, view, partitioning

I've created a view on partitioned table. When I pass the partitioned column to the SELECT statement of view, the optimizer is not going to that particular partition when checked through EXPLAIN statement.

Is there any way to make the view access a single partition of its table?

[Edit] : Here is how I created the view on two partitioned tables

```
CREATE TABLE Partition1 (ID INT,NAME VARCHAR(100),DOB DATE)
PARTITION BY LIST (YEAR(DOB))
(
    PARTITION P_2000 VALUES IN (2000),
    PARTITION P_2001 VALUES IN (2001)
);

CREATE TABLE NOPART (ID INT,DOB DATE)
PARTITION BY LIST (YEAR(DOB))
(
    PARTITION P_2000 VALUES IN (2000),
    PARTITION P_2001 VALUES IN (2001)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW P_VIEW
AS
SELECT ID,DOB
FROM PARTITION1
UNION
SELECT ID,DOB
FROM NOPART;

EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM P_VIEW
WHERE DOB = '2001-01-01';
```

When I run the "Explain" it shows optimizer is going to both partitions "p_2000" and "p_2001".

Comment: Show us the outputs of `show create table [partitioned table]` and `show create view [your_view]` then we can tell more..

Comment: Please see the updated question above.

Answer (score 1):

There are many deficiencies in the implementation of `VIEWs`.  You *may* have hit one.

There are many uses of `PARTITIONing` that do not provide any performance.  `BY RANGE` is probably the only variant that helps performance for *some* use cases.  A table with less than a million rows is not worth partitioning.

Without seeing your `CREATE TABLE`, `CREATE VIEW`, and `SELECT`, we can only give you vague answers like I have.

(Responding to added code)  Unless there is more to it than that, `PARTITIONing` in that way provide no benefit over having an index on `DOB`.

Furthermore, The `VIEW` + `PARTITION` approach (without an index) must scan the entire `2001` partition looking for the few rows for '2001-01-01'.  Instead the simple index approach can find them immediately -- 365 times as fast.  (OK, not really that much faster, but still.)

Comment: Hi Rick! I've edited my question with a sample code. Please have a look at it.